# Can only use 9.5GB of 16GB of RAM before programs crash

Tags: windows-7, memory

**How can I force Windows to use all 16GB of my RAM?**

I'm running Windows 7 64 bit, have 16GB of RAM and the page file is disabled. I *want* my programs to crash when I'm low on RAM otherwise with a page file the computer...will...just...keep...*has a drink and watches a movie*...getting...slower because if I need more RAM I will *buy more RAM* instead of wasting money on a whole new computer.

For some reason though programs crash at 9.5GB of RAM usage. Even if I'm just under everything is exceptionally responsive and I'm very happy with the stability of the software regardless of how much RAM it is using. The problem is that I should be able to use all 16GB of RAM but I get the warnings that I'm low on memory. Now I'm very aware that even with Superfetch disabled Windows absolutely insists on wasting RAM and every now and then I empty out the modified page list, the standby and the priority 0 in [RAMMap](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/rammap.aspx). However even when accounting for that RAM usage and RAMMap's usage I should still have another 6.5GB of accessible RAM. WTH?

Is it possible that there is something wrong with the RAM and a portion of it has been isolated from being utilized? I imagine the system simply wouldn't POST (boot) if a dimm was bad. I *cold* buy another 16GB of RAM but is this a percentage bug where if I had 32GB I could only use say 24GB? I haven't been able to find anything else though if I do independently find a working answer I'll post it here myself.

Comment: "The problem is that I should be able to use all 16GB of RAM but I get the warnings that I'm low on memory." - This means you are low on virtual memory, caused by you, not having a large enough page file.

Comment: Low on memory warnings have nothing to do with a shortage of available RAM. It means you are approaching the commit limit and that can happen even with plenty of available RAM. This is not a bug. Enable the pagefile, preferably system managed, and the problem should be solved.

Comment: You could try testing with [EmptyStandbyList.exe](https://wj32.org/wp/software/empty-standby-list/) and schedule a process to free up memory every so often (e.g. `EmptyStandbyList.exe standbylist`). Since you're using RAMMap then check out https://betanews.com/2016/03/11/how-to-free-up-ram-from-the-command-line/ for more detail. Just test with the options, etc. I assume this won't work on Windows 7 but you might check just to confirm; I've gotten it setup on Server 2008 (non R2) in the paste for a memory leak issue at the OS level and this was the patch along with EmptyStandbyList.exe.

Comment: Yes, this could be a bug by the way, either an OS bug and perhaps you need to update Windows with Windows Update and it could be a memory leak bug with any software you run on this system as well. Unless you free up the garbage memory or whatever is sucking it up, it'll just top out. Check Task Manage `Performance` tab and see what cache is free versus available. When Microsoft didn't release the Dynamic Cache service fix that freed of the RAM just as the EmptyStandbyList.exe did, I used EmptyStandbyList.exe to resolve until MS release they're patch for the issue.

Comment: As others have said, this is a result of low virtual memory not low physical memory. How much free or available RAM you have has nothing to do with the problem. (It's like asking why you can't write any more checks when you still have money in the bank.) And no modern OS can make efficient use of physical memory without sufficient paging space.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Windows 7 (and very likely other versions of Windows) do *not* properly report the amount of RAM being used.

In the Task Manager the default memory column is the "Memory (Private Working Set)" however this is misleading. I had installed MariaDB (a replacement for MySQL) and programs would crash at very low levels of *reported* RAM usage.

After receiving some insight I discovered that the correct way to gauge *actual* RAM usage in Windows 7 was to look at the *commit*. In the processes tab click on the *View* menu, *Select Columns...* and then check the option *Commit Size*. With MariaDB it was *much* larger than the Private memory. In the Performance tab at the bottom is the System information and the last item is the *Commit (GB)* however it will only round down to the nearest gigabyte (on a system with 16GB of RAM).

Unfortunately I'm past the point of warranting being able to replace existing RAM (4x4GB of DDR3) and so my next system will have at least 32GB (2x16GB).

Microsoft does love to keep lots of irrelevant files in the RAM for very extended periods of time however if you prefer to force the system to clear the RAM of dead weight files I have found it possible using [RAMMap](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/rammap). RAMMap has an *Empty* menu at the top and clearing the junk from memory usually takes about half a minute before I close the program. I do this when I need to close multi-threaded Firefox 52 ESR and decide to load a game.

Generally speaking first most software is at least moderately bloated. Microsoft itself uses an excessive amount of RAM. Secondly Windows *keeps* things in RAM when it shouldn't. Thirdly users who are not aware of what purely optional programs are running should learn the differentiate what should and what should not be running. Lastly until operating systems manage RAM usage better either having sufficient amount of RAM with the page file disabled or closing one large RAM-utilizing program before opening another will always yield greater performance than grinding away at a hard drive (SSD or mechanical) with excess that the operating system loads and keeps in the RAM. The more you know the more you can do.

Comment: "*Microsoft does love to keep lots of irrelevant files in the RAM for very extended periods of time*" Of course it does, as all modern OSes do. Keeping stuff in memory is free if that memory isn't needed for any other purpose. And if the file happens to get accessed, a disk operation is avoided.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Then you clearly do not understand proper memory management. Yes, avoiding disk operations is important though passive junk in the memory is always less important than active tasks and high performance. That is what you are clearly demonstrating a lack of comprehension for.

Comment: There is no tradeoff here. You don't have to have memory free now to use it later. You can use it now *and* use it later. Every modern OS works this way, and it's for a very good reason. Your issue has literally nothing to do with how your physical memory is being used.